# Switch statement to add specific variable to api request

Tags: go, variables, switch-statement

I am trying to use a switch statement in which a user will be asked for input and their selection will be scanned into a specific variable that can be found in the switch statement. Once the choice is save to the variable (p, h, i) the variable will then be added as a parameter as seen in params.Add("filter", fmt.Sprintf("hostname:%s", h)). Once one of the variables have been added to the Add method they will then be passed via the api request. Am I way off with my thought process?

```
func FindHost() (*HostSearch, error) {
    fmt.Println("Select from the options below:")
    var choice int
    fmt.Println("1. Platform")
    fmt.Println("2. Hostname")
    fmt.Println("3. IP")
    fmt.Scanln(&choice)
    switch choice {
    case 1:
        var p string
        fmt.Println("Enter Platform name: ex Windows")
        fmt.Scanln(p)

    case 2:
        var h string
        fmt.Println("Enter hostname: ")
        fmt.Scanln(h)

    case 3:
        var i string
        fmt.Println("Enter IP")
        fmt.Scanln(i)

    }
    
    params := url.Values{}
    params.Add("filter", fmt.Sprintf("hostname: '%s'", h))
    params.Add("filter", fmt.Sprintf("platform_name: '%s'", p))
    params.Add("filter", fmt.Sprintf("IP: %s", i))

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", <URL>+<api endpoint>+params.Encode(), nil)
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
}
```

Comment: Is this for a command line program that sends a HTTP request?

Comment: Yes, correct. This is one of the functions that will make up the program. There will be a menu and you select platform, hostname, or ip. Then the switch statement will ask for you to enter the hostname, platform, of ip.

Comment: if this is going to be a command line program, it would be possible to use flags or command line arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just going to be command line program, you should use command line arguments, and whatever value is passed (one/couple of host/IP/platform) use that in the function. You could use golang [flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) .

If you want to stick the original program, here is what you need to do.

```
func FindHost() {
    fmt.Println("Select from the options below:")
    var choice int
    var param string
    params := url.Values{}
    fmt.Println("1. Platform")
    fmt.Println("2. Hostname")
    fmt.Println("3. IP")
    fmt.Scanf("%d", &choice)
    switch choice {
    case 1:
        fmt.Println("Enter Platform name: ex Windows")
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &param)
        params.Add("filter", fmt.Sprintf("hostname: '%s'", param))

    case 2:
        fmt.Println("Enter hostname: ")
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &param)
        params.Add("filter", fmt.Sprintf("platform_name: '%s'", param))

    case 3:
        fmt.Println("Enter IP")
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &param)
        params.Add("filter", fmt.Sprintf("IP: %s", param))

    }
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%+v", params))
}
```

*UPDATE*

update the program as per recent comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would have used flags, but this is meant to be a menu within a menu. When the user selects 1. Platform, 2. Hostname, or 3. IP the switch statement will then prompt them to enter the search term. The issue is when they do this I do not know how I could use the corresponding variable to plug itself into the correct param.add and only pass that to the api request. Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: @ioj, you should use the flag as -host,-ip, -platform, if will use the non-empty value of the flag in params, if multiple params does not work, then add a validation.